# shouldOverrideUrlLoading randomly called

Tags: android, webview

**PROBLEM**

My `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` gets called only in first instance of `WebFragment` that holds my `WebView`. But when I go to another instance of `WebFragment` it does not get called. However it does get called when I click on links.

Steps to trigger this error:

`WebFragment` -replace-> `SearchFragment` -replace with new instance of `WebFragment` -> `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` not called

**CODE**

*WebView*

```
public void init() {
    this.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains("login")) {
                presenter.requestLogIn();
                return false;
            } else {
                urlStack.add(url);
            }

            Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
            extraHeaders.put("header", "header_info");

            loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
            return true;
        }
    });

    getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

private void addCookies(WebPresenter presenter) {
    if (presenter.createProperCookie(getContext()) != null) {
        List<HttpCookie> cookies = HttpCookie.parse(presenter.createProperCookie(getContext()));

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();
                cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void load(String url) {
    addCookies(presenter);
    loadUrl(url);
}
```